# Automatic deletion of spaces on asp.net tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Little question out of annoyment with Visual Studio 2010. Whenever I write lines like this:

```
<%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.AccountName) %>
```

And save the file, some lines (some, not all of them, haven't figured out the logic behind this yet) will be converted to this:

```
<%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.AccountName)%>
```

Quite subtle difference, but I was wondering which magic happens here. Anyone got an idea? And perhaps an idea how to switch this magic off?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on Visual Studio 2008:

```
[Tools -> Options]

TextEditor -> XML -> Formatting -> Auto Reformat

- On paste from clipboard
- On completion of end tag
```

Comment: Thanks, willdo for VS2010 as well. I did actually search the TextEditor Options menu, but didn't realise this should go under XML. Will check whether or not this will do the trick!!

Comment: Tested it two days, but doesn't work completely unfortunately. Still, on pasting text into <%: %>, the space gets deleted. So I'm thinking two things at the moment: or the formatting of asp.net is not working with the xml formatting options, or it's some weird bug in Visual Studio.

Comment: Try other settings for HTML, XAML and XML. I definitely got it under control myself just don't remember exactly how.